# Call JS function in html on server side (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have an index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Server-side Example</title>
        <script src="./CircleArea.js"></script>
            </head>
    <body>
        <input
        id="ftpd"
        type="button"
        value="Calculate"
        onclick="CircleArea()"
        />
    </body>
</html>
```

It calls the CircleArea.js file.

```
const PI = 3.14
let radius = 3;

    function circleArea(){
         var inputField = document.createElement("INPUT");
         inputField.setAttribute("type", "text");
         inputField.setAttribute("value", (PI*radius*radius));
         document.body.appendChild(inputField);
    }
    
    module.exports ={circleArea}; // This I added for nodejs
```

It works fine. But I now want to run Index.html on the server-side.

I added server.js

```
let http = require('http');
let fs = require('fs');

let handleRequest = (request, response) => {
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });
    fs.readFile('./Index.html', null, function (error, data) {
        if (error) {
            response.writeHead(404);
            respone.write('Whoops! File not found!');
        } else {
            response.write(data);
        }
        response.end();
    });
};

http.createServer(handleRequest).listen(8000); 
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:8000');
```

Now `node server.js`

gives error

```
CircleArea.js:1 
        
       Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
(Index):13 
        
       Uncaught ReferenceError: CircleArea is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((Index):13:6)
```

My question is how should I modify Index.html and CircleArea.js to run it on nodejs?

Comment: Please don't fix your code by applying an answer. Now, a part of my answer doesn't make sense. I rollback the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has nothing to do with server-side evaluation. You're using Node.js as a web server. The server doesn't evaluate the client code. It doesn't import `CircleArea.js`. You don't need

```
module.exports ={circleArea}; // This I added for nodejs
```

and should remove it. It's a CommonJS module export and not allowed in browser code.

A web browser sends a request for `index.html`. The server responds with the content of `Index.html`. The browser evaluates it. It finds a script tag for `./CircleArea.js` and sends a request for this file. The server responds with the content of `Index.html` because there is no routing in the server. Open the dev tools in your browser to see the problem. The server responds with the same data (the content of `Index.html`) for all requests. You have to implement routing.

```
let http = require('http');
let fs = require('fs');

let handleRequest = (request, response) => {
  let file = 'Index.html';
  if (request.url === '/CircleArea.js') {
    file = 'CircleArea.js';
    response.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'application/javascript',
    });
  } else {
    response.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html',
    });
  }
  fs.readFile('./' + file, null, function (error, data) {
    if (error) {
      response.writeHead(404);
      response.write('Whoops! File not found!');
    } else {
      response.write(data);
    }
    response.end();
  });
};

http.createServer(handleRequest).listen(8000);
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:8000');
```

This is a very basic and simple solution. You can use it for a very simple routing. For a more complex routing I recommend a framework like [Nest.js](https://nestjs.com/)

Comment: The errors remain the same after replacing the content of server.js according to your suggestions. I think I am not getting your point and am still not able to call CircleArea() function.

Comment: @Shahgee I fixed my code. You have typos in your code. You have `response` and `respone` and `CircleArea()` and `circleArea()`. Keep in mind that code and most file systems are case-sensitive. `Index.html` is not `indext.html`.

Comment: @Shahgee A working live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-8els8f?file=server.js